# Bruteforce 4 digit code and add it as argument Python

Tags: python

Right now I am working on an ethical hacking project. My knowledge of pen testing is good, but my programming skills are lacking. I have been working out how to do this for hours now but my attempts have been fruitless.
I need to create a program in python that "bruteforces" a 4 digit code and adds it as an argument when running an executable file.
Cheers Guys and have a great weekend.
Edit: If more detail is require I am more than happy to provide.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Please post your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: what about 4 nested `for` loops?

Comment: Get a copy of this [book](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/effective-python-penetration-testing)